# Application stopped unexpectedly. Force close. what to do?

Tags: java, android, opencv, camera, frame

```
public void onManagerConnected(int status) {

          switch (status) {
              case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
              {
                  Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");


                  System.loadLibrary("detection_based_tracker");


                  try {

InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.lbpcascade_frontalface);

File cascadeDir = getDir("cascade", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

mCascadeFile = new File(cascadeDir, "lbpcascade_frontalface.xml");

FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(mCascadeFile);


                      byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                      int bytesRead;
                      while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                          os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                      }
                      is.close();
                      os.close();


                      mJavaDetector = new CascadeClassifier(mCascadeFile.getAbsolutePath());



                      if (mJavaDetector.empty()) {
                          Log.e(TAG, "Failed to load cascade classifier");
                          mJavaDetector = null;
                      } else
         Log.i(TAG, "Loaded cascade classifier from " + mCascadeFile.getAbsolutePath());

                      cascadeDir.delete();
                  } catch (IOException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                      Log.e(TAG, "Failed to load cascade. Exception thrown: " + e);
                  }

                  mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
              } break;
              default:
              {
                  super.onManagerConnected(status);
              } break;
          }
      }
  };



  public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) 
    {


        mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
        mGray = inputFrame.gray();



        if (mAbsoluteFaceSize == 0) {
            int height = mGray.rows();
            if (Math.round(height * mRelativeFaceSize) > 0) {
                mAbsoluteFaceSize = Math.round(height * mRelativeFaceSize);
            }



        }


          MatOfRect faces = new MatOfRect();

          if (mDetectorType == JAVA_DETECTOR){   
                  if (mJavaDetector != null)
     mJavaDetector.detectMultiScale(mGray, faces, 1.1, 2, 2,  
                       new Size(mAbsoluteFaceSize, mAbsoluteFaceSize), new Size());

           }

          else {
              Log.e(TAG, "Detection method is not selected!");
          }


  Rect[] facesArray = faces.toArray();
 for (int i = 0; i < facesArray.length; i++)
            {

  Core.rectangle(mRgba, facesArray[i].tl(), facesArray[i].br(), FACE_RECT_COLOR, 5);
    }
    return mRgba;

}
```

While executing this code for face detection. I got this, application stopped unexpectedly.I  decided to do face detection without any options and all. So can anybody suggest me what's wrong with my code.

Thanks in advance.

logcat
 01-24 09:50:04.605: D/dalvikvm(335): newInstance failed: p0 i0 [0 a1

01-24 09:50:04.605: D/AndroidRuntime(335): Shutting down VM

01-24 09:50:04.605: W/dalvikvm(335): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)

01-24 09:50:04.625: E/AndroidRuntime(335): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

01-24 09:50:04.625: E/AndroidRuntime(335): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.faces/com.example.faces.MainActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.example.faces.MainActivity

01-24 09:50:04.625: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)

01-24 09:50:04.625: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)

01-24 09:50:04.625: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)

01-24 09:50:04.625: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)

01-24 09:50:04.625: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

01-24 09:50:04.625: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

01-24 09:50:04.625: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)

01-24 09:50:04.625: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

01-24 09:50:04.625: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)

01-24 09:50:04.625: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)

01-24 09:50:04.625: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)

01-24 09:50:04.625: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

01-24 09:50:04.625: E/AndroidRuntime(335): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.example.faces.MainActivity

01-24 09:50:04.625: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)

01-24 09:50:04.625: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)

01-24 09:50:04.625: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)

01-24 09:50:04.625: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)

01-24 09:50:04.625: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  ... 11 more

Comment: please give us an error stacktrace...

Comment: Actually no error has been occurred in the console. So i am sending you the logcat.

Comment: I done with attachment of logcat in my question itself. please look over that.

Answer (score 1):

```
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.example.faces.MainActivity
```

Make sure your `MainActivity` class can be instantiated. Some common causes for this:

- The class is `abstract`.
- There is an explicit constructor an it takes arguments. Activities shouldn't really need an explicit constructor. If one is provided, it should take no arguments.

Comment: Edited the answer. Also consider providing additional details in the question. What the exception says that the equivalent of `new com.example.faces.MainActivity()` via reflection failed.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the code you have attached here as I have a working version of the same sample code. Have you added the activity to the AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: Ya.. I had done with attachment of activity to manifest file also.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same issue with this all types of applications said as unexpectedly stopped/please force close. what I did is I totally restored my phone and it helped me avoid this issue again. 
Before restoring be sure that all your needed docs and files are safe, transferred to other device or you can download one program from google market which helps in shifting files from file to the other new file in it.
And finally to restore have to go to settings-applications-restore SD card and phone, phone will be switched off and need to start again uploading your gmail account and connected to internet or WiFi.